# hibernate query to compare two date fields in a table

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

I use `PostgreSQL` data base and `hibernate` in my application. I have a table with two fields : `updated_date` timestamp without time zone and `processed_time` timestamp without time zone. I have the following query:

```
String hql = "From WebContentDefinition wcd where  wcd.pageUpdatedDate > wcd.processedTime";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
```

Here `WebContentDefinition` is the pojo corresponding to the table. Now the field `processed_time` might not contain any value sometimes. 
My current query do not return me anything. Is there a solution for this. I want all the rows where updated_date is grater than the processed_time.

Comment: Your query is missing the `where` keyword. I'd start by fixing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, here is how your table looks like:

```
postgres=# select * from WebContentDefinition
postgres-# ;
pageupdateddate   |    processedtime
---------------------+---------------------
2015-09-28 09:41:37 | 2015-09-28 09:41:35
2015-09-26 09:41:37 | 2015-09-26 09:30:35
2015-09-26 09:40:37 |
(3 rows)
```

this is the output of you current query:

```
postgres=# select *  From WebContentDefinition wcd where  wcd.pageUpdatedDate > wcd.processedTime;
pageupdateddate   |    processedtime
---------------------+---------------------
2015-09-28 09:41:37 | 2015-09-28 09:41:35
2015-09-26 09:41:37 | 2015-09-26 09:30:35
(2 rows)
```

You can use COALESCE to set processedTime to some old date if its null and then run the same query:

```
postgres=# select pageupdateddate, COALESCE(processedTime, '1900-01-01 00:00:00') from WebContentDefinition;
pageupdateddate   |      coalesce
---------------------+---------------------
2015-09-28 09:41:37 | 2015-09-28 09:41:35
2015-09-26 09:41:37 | 2015-09-26 09:30:35
2015-09-26 09:40:37 | 1900-01-01 00:00:00
(3 rows)
```

Final output of query:

```
postgres=# select *  From WebContentDefinition wcd where  wcd.pageUpdatedDate > COALESCE(wcd.processedTime, '1900-01-01 00:00:00');
pageupdateddate   |    processedtime
---------------------+---------------------
2015-09-28 09:41:37 | 2015-09-28 09:41:35
2015-09-26 09:41:37 | 2015-09-26 09:30:35
2015-09-26 09:40:37 |
(3 rows)
```